# Calculate Salary - Limited countries - Submission also limited currencies

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

So the new Salary Calculator was announced, I like the idea!. It only supports a few countries though. This is always pretty annoying as if you don't live in US, UK, France and Germany you basically are treated as a second-class citizen.

[image]

That said, you can still contribute by offering to submit your salary.
However again the submission then only supports a very select few currencies. Why not spread some love for other countries? We actually exist and want to contribute but it's always pretty demoralizing if not in the select (elite) few countries.

[image]

Comment: Personally it makes me feel like a second rate consideration... so why contribute.

Comment: @Cerbrus bro it's not a duplicate

Comment: How isn't it a dupe?

Comment: I am specifically comparing the limited counties in the search... to the extremely limited set of currencies on the submission

Comment: I could easily see a scenario where the search countries is limited but the submission could be a wider audience

Comment: You can only submit salaries for a specific set of countries. Why should other currencies than those used in those countries be supported? In the end, the issue is the extremely limited list of countries.

Comment: Alright, suppose it just sucks that many of us are treated like second class citizens.